# How to set SyslogIdentifier in [SERVICE] section of systemd service file as empty?

Tags: systemd

I want to set `SyslogIdentifier`  in `[SERVICE]` section of `systemd` service file as *empty*, so that nothing is prefixed in the logs. I tried below options:

1)  Mentioning nothing:
`SyslogIdentifier=`
>>> Result: Similar to default behaviour, logs get prefixed with process name.

2) Empty String:
`SyslogIdentifier=""`
>>> Result: Empty string with double quotations (" ") got prefixed as it is.

3) Escape Character:
`SyslogIdentifier=\s`
>>> Result: \s got prefixed to the logs.

4) Empty Space:
`SyslogIdentifier=   (few blank spaces)`
>>> Result: Similar to default behaviour, logs get prefixed with process name.

5) Spaces enclosed in single quotes:
`SyslogIdentifier='  '`
>>> Result: Single quotes ('  ') got prefixed as it is.

I don't want anything getting prefixed to the logs.

Could anyone please tell me how to do that ?

[Reference:](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

> `SyslogIdentifier=`
>
> Sets the process name to prefix log lines sent to the logging system
>   or the kernel log buffer with. If not set, defaults to the process
>   name of the executed process. This option is only useful when
>   `StandardOutput=` or `StandardError=` are set to `syslog`, `journal` or `kmsg`
>   (or to the same settings in combination with `+console`).

Answer (score 7):

One way to do that is to use a [zero-width space](https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/) as `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER`.
If you don't know how to type/enter it just copy/paste the line below (as it already contains a zero-width space after the `=` sign...)

```
SyslogIdentifier=​
```

Comment: This will prepend a zero-width space to the logs though, which, depending on your log viewer, you may not see, or may see as a character sequence that shows its binary representation.

Comment: Imagine the look on your co-workers' faces when they find out what's hiding in the logs.